# Authentication in single-user API

Tags: php, laravel, api, authentication

In my API, there is no data assigned to any users, it's just about protection to prevent unauthorized people from using it. What are some possibilities of securing such kind of API?

I know there are JWTs, oAuth etc., but are they suitable for such simple API structure? I thought about just storing the single API key and make clients send it, but I heard it's not very safe. I would like to skip using database for this API entirely. What are the possibilities?

I'm using PHP and Laravel 5.4.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on how many users you have.

If you want to give multiple users access it would be recommended to give them separate API keys.

If it is just one user, keep it simple and use a single API key.

In general, API keys can be compromised but it's always a consideration of functionality and what protection you need. Look at the Eventbrite API or Google Maps API. The public interfaces work by sending your API key only, Google adding some layers of security by doing checks what website the request came from.

Eventbrite is doing no checks here since all the API does is return structured data for the events which are public anyways and don't count against any limits.